# start activity class before widget provider

Tags: android, widget

I make a widget. I want to start with a widget for the first time start up
activity (gallery) which can be used select theme widget. And after selecting disappeared, and appeared widget as the widget HTC clock or HTC calendar. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank

Comment: sure but first post your widget code than i will edit it for starting an activity on first start up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your onUpdate method of `AppWidgetProvider`:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            appid = appWidgetIds;
            rview = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            Intent launchAppIntent = new Intent(context,Activityselecttheme.class);
            launchAppIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetId);

            PendingIntent pendingActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, launchAppIntent, 0);
            rview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingActivity);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rview);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not really working.
I must do something to change in the manifest?

Comment: if i'm right then you want to open an Config Activity on widget click or in fist time start right?

Comment: I want to open activity in the first time the widget starts

Comment: i don't want that after running the widget would be the opportunity to run this activity again, I want it only when adding a widget for the first time.
Thank!

Comment: you have added this line `android:configure="YOU_PACKGE_NAME_Activityselecttheme"` in `appwidget_provider.xml` ?

Comment: or you can see this tuts for launching an Config Activity [app widget](http://www.androidbook.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=3300&downerUserId=satya)

Comment: if i add this line android:configure="YOU_PACKGE_NAME_Activityselecttheme" in appwidget_provider.xml
then clicking on the widget it opens I needed activity,
but the choice is not added widget on the screen

Comment: that is, now I need to call activity widget provider, but what I do not understand ...

Comment: as i known it not possible to add a widget on home screen by coding

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I realized my mistake, I'm a fool. I rewrote the class activity to preference activity and apparently came out as I need.